# sum of timediffs without overlaps mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table like this one:

```
ID  | activity        | start               | end
372 | Machine Running | 2018-01-30 21:19:42 | 2018-01-30 21:52:41
373 | Order Active    | 2018-01-30 21:19:42 | 2018-01-30 21:45:02
374 | Operator Active | 2018-01-30 21:19:42 | 2018-01-30 21:52:41
375 | Reporting Active| 2018-01-30 21:19:48 | 2018-01-30 21:20:06
376 | Admin Active    | 2018-01-30 21:20:09 | 2018-01-30 21:52:41
378 | Order Active    | 2018-01-30 21:49:23 | 2018-01-30 21:52:41
982 | Machine Running | 2018-02-20 15:01:55 | 2018-02-20 15:01:55
983 | Order Active    | 2018-02-20 15:01:55 | 2018-02-20 15:01:55
984 | Operator Active | 2018-02-20 15:01:55 | 2018-02-20 15:01:55
986 | Machine Running | 2018-02-20 15:02:30 | 2018-02-20 15:02:30
987 | Order Active    | 2018-02-20 15:02:30 | 2018-02-20 15:02:30
988 | Operator Active | 2018-02-20 15:02:30 | 2018-02-20 15:02:30
```

I have to find the time the machine is running and the time where nothing is done.
So the time where the machine is running is easy. it is just the timediff of start and end time.

But for every machine running in the table i need a row with "machine doing nothing". in my mind i have to subtract the timediffs of all activities belonging to one machine run from the total time the machine is running without overlaps but i have no clue how to do that.

so for the table above i need an output like this

```
start      | activity        | seconds
2018-07-02 | Machine Running | xx 
2018-07-02 | Doing nothing   | xx
2018-06-27 | Machine Running | xx
2018-06-27 | Doing nothing   | xx
```

Comment: So the doing nothing is the difference between the end time for a machine running row and the start time of the next machine running row? What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: the doing nothing is where there is nothing happening from start to end of machine running. it has nothing todo with the next machine start. just with the activities happening within start and endtime of machine running @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each interval of type `Machine Running` you will need to find all overlapping intervals of type `Operator Active` - I mean overlapping between `Machine Running` and `Operator Active`. Then you have to subtract the **overlapping** of each `Operator Active` from the corresponding `Machine Running`. The end result will be the duration of `Doing nothing`.

For this you will need a formula to calculate the overlapping between 2 time intervals

```
GREATEST(0,interval_1_end - interval_1_start - GREATEST(0,interval_1_end - interval_2_end) - GREATEST(0,interval_2_start - interval_1_start))
```

Intervals must be represented as UNIX timestamps.

And then something like this

```
SELECT t1.start, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.start) AS total_time, SUM(
GREATEST(0,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.start)
  - GREATEST(0,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.end)) 
  - GREATEST(0,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.start) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.start)))
) AS do_nothing /* duration in seconds */
FROM tbl AS t1
LEFT JOIN tbl AS t2 ON (t2.start BETWEEN t1.start AND t1.end)
  OR (t2.end BETWEEN t1.start AND t1.end)
WHERE t1.activity = 'Machine Running' AND t2.activity = 'Operator Active'
GROUP BY t1.start
```